Resolution of current in solenoid in order to analyze magnetic field?
So i came across this question in one of my tests, it asked something appearing very easy,It actually asked "If radius of solenoid is R and that of wire wrapped on it is r then comment about the magnetic field at the mid point of axis of solenoid" This was a multiple choice question with one or more correct however and thus i chose the options (A) and (C)(refer image) which said the magnetic field at the centre of axis is zero and this were incorrect as magnetic field is non zero and independent of "r", but on checking the solution it appeared that what i thought was the wrong approach to this question and the actual approach was a suprising one, they resolved current along length of solenoid and along curvature and then commented about the magtneic field.I never heard that current can also be resolved provided its not a vector and does not obey vector laws despite having direction.
Second thing is magnetic field on the mid point of axis should also depend on Current as if (I=0 then B=0) but (D) option is also given as an answer i.e it does not depends on current.
Pls give me a more detailed approach to this
question.



Pls note that "incorrect statements" were asked.

At what level of education was this question aimed at?

@Farcher higher secondary
